# If $\alpha\neq0$ is an algebraic number, then $e^{\alpha}$ is a transcendental number

Tags: complex-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

How do I prove this? I've tried to search it by the name of "Hermite-Lindemann's" theorem but I don't find anything. If someone has a reference link or something, i would appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know, but could *this* be helpful? $\longrightarrow$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186752/proof-that-ex-is-a-transcendental-function-of-x

Comment: This is a special case of  the [Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: More specifically, this is [Lindemann's theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lindemann_theorem).

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks, but i need a formal proof of the theorem, by chance do you have it?

Comment: See Alan Baker, *Transcendental Numbers Theory*, theorem 1.4 (Cambridge University Press)

Comment: At a basic level, Niven, Irrational Numbers. https://books.google.com/books?id=ov-IlIEo47cC&pg=PR7&lpg=PR7&dq=Irrational+Numbers&source=bl&ots=CvtnNVOvUJ&sig=l0o9oKeKJ_u0Fs5ZtfZQwcZedgA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAzMH_rIPYAhUKz2MKHWRODfYQ6AEIaTAN#v=onepage&q=Irrational%20Numbers&f=false

Comment: [Analytic Proof Of The Lindemann Theorem](https://msp.org/pjm/1952/2-2/pjm-v2-n2-p11-s.pdf)